# iOS Universal deeplinking without third party app

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I am implementing universal deeplinking, I don't want to use any third party framework I have the domain and I have uploaded the apple-app-site association file. Now I want to test if everything is correct or not. How to create the universal link, how to specify ios url scheme and app id in the link ?

Comment: If you have uploaded the apple-app-site association file you should already know the link? It is https://yourserver/yourpath. The association file contains a bundle id for an app to call and the paths that should open the app. The docs at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html are fine.

Comment: https://appsitedemo.herokuapp.com/apple-app-site-association

Comment: Clicking on above link open my app. But if app is not installed it is not taking the user to appstore. How to specify appID in the url

Comment: And how to pass custom parameter in the link.

Comment: The app id has to be in reverse domain notation more like:                 "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc",

Comment: could you check the association file.if something is wrong

Comment: I mentioned the team id in the association file

Comment: Why should the link take the user to the app store? Whatever link you use, if the app is not installed your webservice has to redirect to the app store.

Comment: Search for some universal link validator in the web ...

Answer (score 0):

Universal Links do not look any different than normal links with your domain. If you registered your AASA at `yourdomain.com/apple-app-site-association` then `yourdomain.com/?example=data` should open your app. In the comments you mentioned you want it to open the app store if its not installed. You'll actually need to redirect your link to go to the app store. The Universal Link will not automatically handle that. So `yourdomain.com/` will actually need to return a 301 redirect to the app store url. [Branch](http://docs.branch.io) links have that functionality built in if you'd like to save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks a lot @clayjones94. I wanted to know how do I get the parameters if the app is redirected to App Store. And how will the server handle whether to redirect to App Store if app is not present. It would be of great help if I could get an elaborate answer.